# How do I reset azure deployment credentials?

Tags: azure, ftp, azureportal

I have accidentally set a user name / password for FTP access through App -> Deployment Credentials -> FTP user name / password in azure portal.

I do not want FTP access to my sire / account. The action that I did set my user level credential for all apps on my account which is not what i desired.

How do I reset my credentials? I do not want a different FTP username, rather remove FTP access to my site completely. I followed the steps in [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaushal/2013/05/29/windows-azure-web-sites-reset-your-deployment-credentials-vs-reset-your-publish-profile-credentials/), but I cannot find the the "Quick Glance" menu in the new portal.

Answer (score 0):

Use the 'Reset publish profile' button on the Overview blade of the App in the Azure portal.

It's situated in the top right here:
[image: Azure portal: Reset publish profile]

**Edit 1:**
Completely removing FTP access to the App Service is not (yet) supported, but the option is under review as you can read here: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps/suggestions/8211222-option-to-disable-ftp-and-force-ftps-in-azure-we

**Edit 2:**

> **User-level credentials**: one set of credentials for the entire Azure account. It can be used to deploy to App Service for any app, in any subscription, that the Azure account has permission to access. These are the default credentials set that you configure in App **Services** > <**app_name**> > **Deployment credentials**. This is also the default set that's surfaced in the portal GUI (such as the **Overview** and **Properties** of your app's resource blade).

Source: [Configure deployment credentials for Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-deployment-credentials)

Comment: this won't remove the ftp access complitely as requested

Comment: This does not help. I want to remove the FTP credentials. I accidentally set it and I think its a security issue not being able to revoke the access.

Comment: As I said in **Edit 1**: you can't (which is actually the answer, although it might not be the answer you _wanted_) . Re-creating the app might help, but if you have the User-level credentials set, that won't help either.